# Is it necessary to create "small, normal, large and xlarge android xml layouts" folders if i want my application to run of all Android devices

Tags: android, layout, screen

I am developing an Android Application that supports all kind of Android devices like mobiles and tablets. But it's time consuming to create multiple folders (small, normal, large and xlarge android xml layouts) to support all the Android devices. Is there any way to build an android app that runs on all android devices without creating these folders:small, normal, large, xlarge etc?

Comment: No, you can put everything in folders without any postfixes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android we need to maintain different folders for the layouts with different resolution reason behind it is the use or the resolution of the Android Device on which the application gonna execute.

- **small**    Resources for small size screens.
- **normal**   Resources for normal size screens. (This is the baseline size.)
- **large**    Resources for large size screens.
- **xlarge**   Resources for extra large size screens.

Android OS select the specific layout it self by checking the compatible device and its resolution.

**So, better to create folders to support in multiple screens**

For More Info refer [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: i think your answer is not related to this question, OP's mean is did he/she must create multiple folder for multiple screen size (4,5,6 ,... inch layout-large , layout-small) but your answer is about `dpi` that is not related to screen size.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to create unique layouts (ie. *layout_mdpi* ) if you want something unique for that particular screen size.

If you want to use the same layout on all different screen sizes, you will only need to create a single layout (in the *layout* folder).

Only if you want to customize a particular layout would you need a new FOLDER in layouts (named: layout_mdpi) in that folder you would have multiple copies of customized layout with same name (ex. my_layout.xml)

To clearly answer your question - you will only need the layout folder and no other ones in your casel

Ex.

```
res\layout\my_layout.xml  // this folder is all you need if this layout will work on all screen sizes
res\layout_mdpi\my_layout.xml // you ONLY need this if you are presenting something unique on this screen size.
```

Comment: Thanks. So you mean if there are 5 xml layouts then there would be "layout_mdpi, layout_hdpi, etc" for each of the xml layouts in layout folder?

Comment: clarified in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to build an android app that runs on all android devices without creating these folders:small, normal, large, xlarge etc

Consider this, you have a button (with match_parent) that stretches full width of a screen in portrait mode of a 4 inch phone, that's fine it looks alright, but then that same layout on a 10 inch tablet in portrait is now 3-4inch wide, that's not great looking.

"So what" you say, make it wrap content, okay then so the button now only fills up part of the width on phone, still looks okay but then on a tablet you have huge amount of space now either side of the button, maybe that's looks okay, maybe not.

Maybe same button on a smaller screen takes up too much space?

Now apply the above to every single layout element in your app.

Do you think it'll look good, using the same layout, do you think your users will be okay with an app that was so little care to its UI and UX?

SO, in conclusion, yeah it's possible to only use one eg normal, for all devices but it'll probably look terrible on most of them.